# Is this a correct way in python to find out the that a specific name is in the string for how many max no of times continously

Tags: python, string, error-checking

Program for finding a specific name that is in continous no of times. E.g 'yaweryaweryaweraliyawer' here yawer is for 3 maximum no of times continously.

```
##Created a string to checking for a specific name successive no of times.   

string = 'yaweraliyaweryaweryawer'
##this is the name to find

name = 'yawer'

##max no of times name is in the string 
count = string.count(name)
##reverse loop for checking 
for i in range(count,0,-1):
      if name * count in string:
            print(f"No of successive times {name} is in string is : {count})
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there, just remove name*count with counter "i"

like this:

```
for i in range(count,0,-1):
      if name * i in string:
            print(f"No of successive times {name} is in string is : {i}")
            break;
```

Comment: No i mean that is it a good way to find ? or my code looks bad?